# Keras fit_generator not using all cores on COLAB gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am running a Keras model with tensorflow backend. It works on a desktop - although all 16 cores of my windows machine are not used.

I ported it to Googles' COLAB and ran it there. I am using keras' fit_genrator as the dataset has 34 M training pairs. The issue is that the speedup from the 2000+cores is completely absent - basically no improvement. Has anyone experienced this?

I saw some discussion of a similar issue here
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7732

The code itself is an implementation of skipgrams -

SkipGram.fit_generator(batch_manager,     epochs=epochs,
                                 verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=True,  max_queue_size=50  )

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if its my data pipeline...can see that not much ram is being used...

Comment: What batch size are you using? try increasing it.

Comment: Experimented with 16 to 75000 samples....

Comment: So this is interesting behavior- I wrote a batch generator, that inherited from Sequence, as the docs indicate that fit_generator requires threadsafe data generation. However, it appears that we need not do that for the situation of a single GPU like COLAB. In fact what works is a simple fit_generator.I went back to my basic version and its chugging along at 30 mins per epoch (still long but shorter than the three ours on my 16 core cpu) . Is multiprocessing just about CPU cores in fit_generator?